# Send file via bluetooth between two android phone

Tags: android

I want to write a programme for sending a file/image between two android phone. If I already have the dirtectory of my file/image，how can I write the programme?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all you need to make Bluetooth Connection with the destination Android Phone. After doing this. you need to send File in bytes using `DataOutputStream` Class. Also look for following useful link,

http://kpbird.blogspot.com/2011/04/android-send-image-via-bluetooth.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. But if the file/picture is in the SD card. Is it the same way to handle?I also want to know how to write the program for the receiver side

Comment: yes, if it is in SD card then also you can send. Now for Receiving you need DataInputStream class for fetching file on receiving side. Please accept the answer so that it can be useful for others as well